# identity tensor proof

Tags: matrices, determinant, tensors

Can someone explain how can I prove the identity tensor multiplicating by a determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix A is again the determinant using Einstein Notation?

$$\det(AI)=\det(A)$$

Comment: $AI = A$ by the definition of the identity $I$.

Comment: I'm learning about tensors and I would like to know how can I prove these using Einstein Notation. I know $\partial_{ij}$ is the identity matrix, how can I represent det(A) ?@CharlesHudgins

Comment: $(AI)_{ij} = A_{ik} I_{kj} = A_{ik} \delta_{kj} = A_{ij}$. Hence $AI = A$. But this is really putting the horse before the cart. The fact that $I_{kj} = \delta_{kj}$ is a theorem (albeit an easy one), whereas $AI = A$ is a definition.

Comment: I see how it works for that particular example. But if I want to show in general what you advice, I cannot see a relation between $det(A)=\Sigma_{i,...,i_n}a_ib_jc_k...$ and the identity tensor $\partial_{kj}$ @CharlesHudgins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AI = A$ by the definition of the identity $I$. If $\det$ is a function (which it is), then we have to have $\det (AI) = \det (A)$.